# Android Studio will not let me type the first line of a layout XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

Often times in Android Studio I will create a new Layout file just by creating a new file in the Layout directory and coding it manually. When I try to type the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` it stops me just before the last ">" and won't let me type it. I can type anything else, just not a ">", when I try nothing happens. I also can't copy and paste that line in.

It will fix itself after I restart Android Studio and allow me to type the ">" again. I thought this might have had something to do with Android Studio's write permissions (though in hindsight that was kinda dumb since it is writing to all other files just fine) so I tried running it as an administrator but the issue is still occurring. I'm running win 8.1 64-bit and using the 64-bit version of the Android Studio 2.0 preview.

Any idea what could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Using US keyboard or AltGr?

Answer (score 0):

Try and copy the line from notepad then paste the line into the xml instead of typing it. Also, you might find with 2.0 preview you may not need that line at all. It may automatically add it to the compiler when you build